# Are class methods pure in dask?

Tags: dask

Is this a valid use of `pure` in Dask?

Lets assume that `bar` is never changed during the computation, but it may change while I setup the computation.

```
from dask import delayed


class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 1
    def foo(self, b):
        return self.bar + b
    def dask_foo(self, b):
        return delayed(self.foo, pure=True)(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is valid use: you are effectively asserting that the `bar` attribute, which is not an argument to the delayed function, will not change for any subsequent calls. When you say something is "pure", then Dask assumes that calling with argument `b=5` will get the same result each time. 
Notice that if you call `dask_foo` with the same value of `b` multiple times, the key of the resulting delayed object will be the same every time. If you have `pure=False`, you get a random UUID part to the key each time.

In this case you are obviously able to break your own assertion by changing the value of `bar`: don't do that!

Comment: So it can change before the graph is executed, but not while it is executing. Thanks!